# What's an 'Unanswered tag'?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

Using main menu option "Unanswered", you get the list of unanwered questions. And the suboption "My Tags" limits this list to only those unanswered questions that are tagged with at least 1 of the tags you are *watching*. Great feature! The more you optimize the set of tags you want to watch, the more this list is personalized to only include questions about topics you are interested in ...

However, to the right of the list of question, there is a block titled "Unanswered Tags". That sounds really weird (to not say wrong). IMO it is rather a block of "Related tags", whereas it contains the list of all tags used in any of the Unanswered questions being shown (with the list of questions being limited to questions tagged with any of the tags I am watching).

Should that block titled be changed (to "Related tags")? Or is it me who doesn't understand what "Unanswered Tags" is all about?

Answer (score 3):

The items in the "Unanswered tags" list take you directly to the list of unanswered questions in that specific tag and the number next to the tag icon is the number of unanswered questions in that tag.

So, the current list here on MSE looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of "Unanswered Tags" on Meta Stack Exchange including "feature-request with 4863 tags]

So, if you click on [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), you'll see the list of 4863 questions with the FR tag that are considered "unanswered" by our definition, or [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/feature-request).

This is not the same as the [22880 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) with or without answers with that tag.

It's a good way to navigate around different tags while restricting the questions you see to those that are unanswered.

Comment: If that is the actual meaning of those tags, then I find it bizarre that they are shown within "my" list of questions, which is constructed based on "my" tags I am watching. Seems to me that they should go (deserve) their own sub-menu titled ... Unanswered tags.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Anytime you're in the unanswered section, this is what's in the sidebar. It doesn't relate to your tags at all.